# Unwanted white space on mobile version

Tags: html, css

I have found a unwanted white space in mobile version of my web site.

this only happens in the mobile versions, in the desktop version everything is normal, I already checked if there is any element with padding-right but I did not find it.

Can you help me?

[www.campobelolanding.com.br](http://www.campobelolanding.com.br)

Comment: This post is lacking in detail, are you able to a) show us where the white space your talking about is or b) explain in greater detail where the white space you are referring to is.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm new to Stack Overflow.
Next time I'll try to add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As Dylan pointed out, you should put more detail in your post so others can find answers in your questions.  Please update your question to include relevant code and more specific details.

Regardless, I did some poking around and found out that your "margmarg" class has margins that are blowing out the page.

It is this line:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .margmarg {
        margin-left: 1.6rem !important;
        margin-right: 1.6rem !important;
    }
}
```

The takeaway is that something with a width of 100% and a margin will end up being more than 100% width of the page.

Comment: Thank you so much Jennifer, I removed the "margmarg" class from all the elements and that was really what was causing the white space, in fact I need that margin, I'm going to study a way to put the margin without causing this problem.
About the lack of information from the post unfortunately I did not find more relevant information to add since I did not know what was causing the problem ...

Comment: You can fix that by putting padding on your "body".  That way all 100% elements inside the body will take up 100% of what's left.