# unwanted white space in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I am facing the same issue mentioned in [Unwanted white space on mobile version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775084/unwanted-white-space-on-mobile-version) and as per the solution there, I looked for the elements which are 100% width and having padding. For such elements, I gave box-sizing: border-box; like below but the issue persist.

```
 input[type=text], input:focus  {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 27px;
    resize: vertical;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Can any one help me how to debug trough inspect, which element is blowing out.  I could not figure out by looking at inspect element, computed styles.

looks fine in vertical view -

[image]

Issue in horizontal view -

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/vky60wz7/1/

Comment: which white space are we talking about? the input white space? the body white space?

Comment: the white space on the right in the body

Comment: Have you tried `body {margin: 0}` ?

Comment: the greyish? if so then your container must have a max width

Comment: @Ainz-sama  Yes the greyish. Am using bootstrap container class. so this would automatically fill as per the screen width right. Please correctt me if my understanding is wrong. How can I give fixed max-widths for responsive page

Comment: instead of `container ` try `container-fluid`

Answer (score 0):

Because max-width is defiened as 540px
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puoBe.png)

if you disable this it will be ok

Answer (score -1):

You can try two things. first instead of `width`, give a `min-width`. Second, check that the parent elements `display` is not affecting this.

Comment: that recommendation is quite bad and will ruin the style. a width of 100% is correct. It will fill all the available space exluding margin/padding. Thats exactly how you want it. with a max width the box can drop smaller then the screen and will appear as if it wouldnt belong there.